# SQL query to sum "earned" values versus the sum of all values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following three tables.

```
Player:
-------
Id, Name

Achievement:
------------
Id, Title, Points

EarnedAchievement:
------------------
Id, PlayerId, AchievementId, EarnedDate
```

I want to select every player's name, their earned achievement points, and their earned achievement points relative to the total sum of achievement points possible to earn (in other words the progress earned by that particular player (earnedPoints/possiblePoints)).

This is what I have so far:

```
select p.Id, p.Name, sum(a.Points) as AP from Player as p
inner join EarnedAchievement as ea on ea.PlayerId = p.Id
inner join Achievement as a on ea.AchievementId = a.Id
group by p.Id, p.Name
order by p.Name
```

This gives me the following:

```
1, Barack Obama, 140
2, Bruce Willis, 125
etc.
```

I want a fourth column that represents the progress earned by the player. (Total achievement points possible to earn is 210, so their progress columns should be 66% and 59% respectively).

Any pointers would be greatly appriciated.

**EDIT:**

Please note that the sum of all achievement points is not constant, so the number 210 would increase when new achievements are added.

Comment: Total of achievement points is always 210 ?

Comment: Is 210 a constant, or derived from somewhere in the database?

Comment: add another derived field to the select with (sum(a.points) / 210) * 100

Comment: 210 is not a constant, it's the sum of all rows in the Achievement table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following, using a cross join with a single valued table:

```
select p.Id, p.Name, sum(a.Points) as AP, cast(sum(a.Points) as decimal)/total.totalSum as Progress
from Player as p
cross join (SELECT SUM(Points) as totalSum FROM Achievement) as total
inner join EarnedAchievement as ea on ea.PlayerId = p.Id
inner join Achievement as a on ea.AchievementId = a.Id
group by p.Id, p.Name, total.totalSum
order by p.Name
```

**Edit**: As mentionned by Joachim Isaksson, with SQL Server, you have to add `total.totalSum` in your group by. This is not mandatory with MySQL.

Tested on [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eefc7/11), it looks fine.

Also note that you should try and avoid cross joins with large tables in general (it's a basic cartesian product, so the number of rows of the result is the product of the numbers of rows of the input tables). Here, however, you're joining with a 1-rowed table, so it's not a probleM

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. However, this query gives me a couple of errors: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "Achievement.Points" could not be bound.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'total'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'totalSum'.

Comment: Looking into it. Btw, for potential future questions, it's very useful to use http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I didn't know about that tool. I will definitely use that in the future, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for putting so much work into this. I'm getting "Column 'total.totalSum' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." now. Could be a MS SQL thing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51530/discussion-between-m-massias-and-morten-salte)

Comment: @MortenSalte For SQL Server, you'll probably need to add `totalsum` to the group by list, MySQL is - let's say - "flexible" in its grouping requirements, SQL Server is not.